# GUI update issue in J2ME

Tags: user-interface, java-me

Let's say I have two forms: `form1` and `form2`.

After pressing a `NEXT_COMMAND` in `form1`, I need to change the value of the `gauge` in `form2` and then show `form2`. Thus:

```
public void commandAction(Command command, Displayable displayable) {
....
else if (displayable == form1) {
    if (command == NEXT_COMMAND) {
        form2_gauge.setValue(value);
        display.setCurrent(form2);
    }
....
}
....
```

However, this doesn't work as I expected it to. It doesn't change a thing at first. On the other hand, if I go back from `form2` to `form1` and then again from `form1` to `form2` it would work.

I can't figure it out myself. I'd be enormously grateful of any possible help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>It seems to me that `form2.gauge` isn't correct here. You have to save the `Gauge` object like this:</s>

```
Gauge form2_gauge([...]);
form2.append(form2_gauge);
```

Then your code would be:

```
[...]
    form2_gauge.setValue(value);
    display.setCurrent(form2);
[...]
```

Have you tried another sequence? Like this:
`display.setCurrent(form2);`
`form2_gauge.setValue(value);`
I don't think it would change anything, but may make it work.

Comment: You've got a sharp eye! Sorry, my fault. But that's not the matter with the code however.

Comment: Well, I certainly *haven't*! It *did* the trick. Can't imagine whhy, though. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Certainly. Sorry I am a bit mentally overwhelmed.